# Why am I getting "undefined method `assert_valid_keys`"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any idea why I am getting this error:

```
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for :widget:Symbol>
```

when I try to do a `Factory.build(:widget)` on the following model:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :designer, :vendor
  # ...
end
```

When I remove the `belongs_to` line the error goes away.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
 belongs_to :designer, :vendor
```

won't work. `:vendor` is treated like an option. And, of course, there isn't such an option. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) for further information.

If you need two `belongs_to` relations, just change your code to:

```
 belongs_to :designer
 belongs_to :vendor
```