# Spree, add controller to admin page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, spree

I'm trying to add my custom controller to admin section in spree 1.3.1
And I failed. I want to see an url to my contoller.index.html in top menu. I;ve did that:

**/controllers/spree/admin/parsers_controller.rb:**

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    #class ParsersController < Spree::Admin::BaseController
    class ParsersController <  Spree::Admin::ResourceController
      def index

      end

    end
  end
end
```

**Deface:**

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/admin",
                     :name => "admin_content_admin_tab_parser",
                     :insert_bottom => "[data-hook='admin_tabs']",
                     :text => "<%= tab :parsers,  :url => spree.admin_parsers_path, :icon => 'icon-th-large' %>",
                     :disabled => false)
```

routes.rb:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :parsers
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Parser index.html</h1>
```

And I'm getting error:

Your receipt gives the same error:

```
NoMethodError in Spree/admin/overview#index
Showing /home/ssa/spree-1.3.1-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.1/app/views/spree/layouts/admin.html.erb where line #54 raised:

undefined method `admin_parsers_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x0000000612a560>
Extracted source (around line #54):

51:           <div class="sixteen columns main-menu-wrapper">
52:             <ul data-hook="admin_tabs" class="inline-menu fullwidth-menu">
53: <%= render :partial => 'spree/admin/shared/tabs' %>
54:             <%= tab(:promotions, :url => spree.admin_promotions_path, :icon => 'icon-bullhorn') %><%= tab(:users, :url => spree.admin_users_path, :icon => 'icon-user') %><%= tab :parsers,  :url => spree.admin_parsers_path, :icon => 'icon-th-large' %>
55: </ul>
56: </div> 
57:         </div>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please explain how you failed.  Your "error" only shows the output HTML, not the actual error. Also: do you have a Rails app that we could clone and attempt to reproduce this error?

Comment: Sorry, It was too late and I've missed an error. Here it is. Unfotunately, rais can't create a path to controller for me. I'm using simple spree 1.3.1 and added few files with few lines of code (they are in the question).Unfortunately, I don't have a code in some public repo. If you need, I can add it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was easy:
[Why am I getting "undefined method `assert_valid_keys`"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507770/why-am-i-getting-undefined-method-assert-valid-keys)

Cant declare in my model: `belongs_to :aThingA, :aThingB`
need:

```
belongs_to :aThingA
belongs_to :aThingB
```