# Unit tests fail after migrating from rails 2.0.1 to 2.3.17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, migration, ruby-1.8.7

After migration from Rails 2.0.1 to 2.3.17 Unit Tests are not working. For each of them I am getting the same error:

> "NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for
>   false:FalseClass".

Any clue?

- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.8.0]
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25

`NoMethodError: undefined method`assert_valid_keys' for false:FalseClass
(eval):12:in `run'
    /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:93:in`send'
    /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:93:in `start_mediator'
    /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/testing/patch/testunit/test/unit/ui/teamcity/testrunner.rb:81:in`start'`

Comment: Could you post an example of how your tests look like?

Comment: I have created new rails 2.3 app and from it took default test_helper.rb and created `test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end`. If I run that test in my app, I still get same error.

Comment: ok, it seems like that method was introduced in rails 3.0 so I think you need to make sure you really are using 2.3

Comment: are you using an invalid syntax like described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507770/why-am-i-getting-undefined-method-assert-valid-keys

Comment: in rails-23app enviroment.rb is set to `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.17' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION`

Comment: @phoet no there is no such case in code

Comment: a stacktrace could help

Comment: @phoet stacktrace added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I have found the solution.

In this app I am working on it is used plugin **fixture_scenarios**, so I have updated lib/fixture_scenarios.rb line #33 which was:

`connection.transaction(Thread.current['open_transactions'] == 0) do`

to

`connection.transaction(:requires_new => Thread.current['open_transactions'] == 0) do`

most of the tests have passed now.